# how to open html file from a directory new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The specific directory contains list of html files. How do I open an html file from a specific directory by click on link using JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you need javascript all you need is the [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) tag

Comment: `<a href="other_directory/no_js_needed.html" target="_blank">Link (open in new window)</a>`

Comment: Also, `"java" != "javascript"`. I've edited the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

like suggested this opens the new html in the same window

```
<a href="other_directory/no_js_needed.html">Link</a>
```

this opens the html in a new window

```
<a href="other_directory/no_js_needed.html" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

javascript inline way same window

```
<a href="other_directory/no_js_needed.html" onclick="location.href=this.href;return false">Link</a>
```

javascript inline new window

```
<a href="other_directory/no_js_needed.html" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false">Link</a>
```

javascript in script tag function

```
<script>
function openlink(link){
location.href=link;
}
openlink('other_directory/no_js_needed.html');
</script>
```

javascript in script tag function in a new window

```
<script>
function openinnewwindow(link){
window.open(link)
}
openinnewwindow('other_directory/no_js_needed.html');
</script>
```

Comment: Really, you're just going to copy and paste my comment?!

Comment: i wrote 6 different ways to do that ? ... any problem if i use your "other_directory/no_js_needed.html" srsly...

Comment: in your comment i see only target _blank..and if we wanna talk about your comment he asks javascript and not html.

Comment: Lol I'm just saying your second example is a straight copy-and-paste from my comment. I'm not saying it was anything revolutionary, but you can't deny you did it.

Comment: i'm new here just trying to help ppl, and if he asks how to link to a file he needs a little more explainetion